# Can VSTS and GitHub Enterprise on the same Azure tenant share a file system?

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, github-enterprise

We're using VSTS, backed by Git, on our Azure tenant. We're considering buying a GitHub Enterprise subscription, to be installed on the same Azure tenant.

In this configuration, can both front-ends point to the same file system, so that they can be used simultaneously for the same repos?

Comment: What do you mean "they can be used simultaneously for the same repos" while VSTS git repo and github repo are two separate git repos?

Comment: That's what I'm asking: if they're installed on the same server, can both repos use the same underlying Git repo. I confess that maybe I just don't understand the tech and that this is a fundamentally stupid queation.

Comment: Again in case it wasnt clear: I'm not talking about github.com hosting I'm talking about GitHub Enterprise, which is the GitHub server software running on OUR server. So they wouldn't have to be different repos, unless there is some fundamental difference between how the two systems work under the hood. Both being Git, I hoped that this wouldn't be the case, but we're looking for verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the backed VSTS account and Github Enterprise in Azure Active Directory, they are not share a file system.